# onRowUnselect event not firing in Angular2

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using Angular2 with PrimeNG components. In `<p-datatable>`, the `onRowUnselect` event is not firing.

Here is my sample code:

```html
<p-dataTable [value]="incidentData" [rows]="3" reorderableColumns="true" (onRowClick)="onRowSelectInvestigation($event)" (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)" [(selection)]="selectedIncident">
```

Comment: Any errors in the console ? Could you also provide the TypeScript part with the `onRowUnselect()` method ?

Comment: Hi Alex, No Errors in console and the corresponding event is not firing

Comment: it won't fire until you add the property that I mentioned below.

Comment: Sorry, Event is not firing, If you have any example please share, Thanks for help

Comment: Try clicking on selected row with control button pressed to unselect it and then your unselect may be called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `selectionMode="single"` to get that method to work.

Comment: since utilizing the example from the site, which works, does not work for you, please provide a plnkr that shows this not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add `selectionMode="single"`

Set `[metaKeySelection]="false"` which turn off metakey so that we can unselect a selected row by clicking on it.

Otherwise click a selected row with ctrl like ctrl+click to unselect it.

Also onRowUnselect won't be called when switching row selection.

**Statement from primeng document ->**
onRowUnselect -> Callback to invoke when a row is unselected with *metakey*.